# Почему выводится крашнутый логотип в NavBar?

Tags: yii2

при попытке вывода логотипа в NavBar получается вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается он не находит картинку, но картинка лежит в одной папке вместе с файлом

вот сам код, возможно я допустил в чем то ошибку:

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => '<img src="1.png" style="display:inline; vertical-align: top; height:32px;">My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'
    ]
]);
```

подскажите в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> картинка лежит в одной папке вместе с файлом

Скорее всего вы храните картинку в закрытой директории, рядом с view файлом.

Вам необходимо понять разницу между относительными и абсолютными ссылками, а также то, что в фреймворке Yii2 корень сайта - это папка, в которой находится индексный файл `index.php` - т.е. папка `web` (`backend/web` или `frontend/web` для `advanced` шаблона), на которую должен быть настроен веб-сервер. Положите файл `1.png` в папку `web`, и используйте ссылки только относительно корня сайта:

```
<img src="/1.png" />
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь все стало понятно